# Google App script crashing on .getSheetByName function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm sorry this is quite basic, and I appreciate the help. Here's a few lines of code that return an  "Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null" error. I'm sure it's something obvious! thanks.

```
const populateGoogleForms = () => {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "TUCC Expense Codes";
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "1adPikAuxJbFEe474pxIKN6Wj_2wEfRoTqZVXyBUf4yE";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();
```

Comment: There must something wrong with your id's or  perhaps you don't have access to the file.  I tried it on my account with this code:`function populateGoogleForms() {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, incidentally, the script needs to be run from the Google Spreadsheet which is "pushing" the options into the Google Form specified by its ID.